# Get Sublist from Dictionary Values in c#

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary "roomDict" and would like to make a list of string property "roomName" from each Room class. Please help!

This is what I was using before with a List:

```
List<string> roomNames = RoomManager.roomDict.Select(rm => rm.roomData.roomName).ToList();
```

But now I have declared the list as a dict and I can't seem to figure out the corresponding code:

```
public static Dictionary<Guid, Room> roomDict = new Dictionary<Guid, Room>();
```

I need a string List to populate a dropdown in Unity. Thanks in advance!

Rik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<string> roomNames = roomDict.Values.Select(rm => rm.roomData.roomName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you have a `Dictionary<Guid,Room>` that you want to convert to a `Dictionary<Guid,string>`, where the string is the name of the room that goes with the Guid. The guids of course should remain unchanged.

That can be accomplished easily with [ToDictionary()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) by changing the value delegate so that it returns the `Name` property instead of the `Room` itself. Simple example with four elements:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Room
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Setup sample data
        var roomDictionary = new Dictionary<Guid,Room>
        {
            { Guid.NewGuid(), new Room { Name = "Room A" } },
            { Guid.NewGuid(), new Room { Name = "Room B" } },
            { Guid.NewGuid(), new Room { Name = "Room C" } },
            { Guid.NewGuid(), new Room { Name = "Room D" } }
        };

        //This is the magic line
        var results = roomDictionary.ToDictionary
        ( 
            pair => pair.Key,          //Keep existing key
            pair => pair.Value.Name    //Substitute Name property instead of the Room itself
        );

        //Output results
        foreach (var pair in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5cc94e3d-f9d3-448e-ad21-12feee335c2b=Room A
83bc6fca-38b0-4e6c-be3a-2e7be1e11932=Room B
ec9d15dd-0f8b-43b8-9db3-62630cf5821f=Room C
ef08e20c-65e0-43f2-953d-f285380b0a78=Room D
```

Here is a [link to a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bz37Wp) if you want to try it out.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I did ask for a list but the dict is better it seems for the task at hand, then I will have the GUID handy. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Values`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx) property to get the Rooms:

```
 roomDict.Values.Select(rm => rm.roomData.roomName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put an object directly into a combo box. The combo box calls .ToString to display. Just override .ToString in your Room Class and you will have all the properties of your object available in the selection.

```
public class Room
    {
        public  int Width { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
private void btnFillCombo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int,Room> rm in dctRoom)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(rm.Value);
            }
        }

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Room rm = (Room)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
            Debug.Print($"Name is {rm.Name}, Width is {rm.Width}, Length is {rm.Length}");
        }
```

to use Debug.Print import System.Diagnostics

Comment: I'll have to try that. Very nice. Much appreciated.